# Which is correct: "get" or "to get"?

Tags: verbs

> All they can do is **get** their children admission in any school and pay the fee for them.

or

> All they can do is **to get** their children admission in any school and pay the fee for them.

Which one is grammatical?

Comment: What do you think is right or wrong about this sentence?

Comment: Including/excluding "to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all hinges on "can" in this case:

What ***can*** they do?

They ***can*** get their children admitted in any school so long as they pay the fee.

You can't say "They can to get," can you? Et voila.